# Error while trying to extend MVCPortlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, liferay, portlet

I'm trying to do a portlet! In additional, I install Liferay IDE on my Eclipse kepler. I created a portlet like this:

**Pom.xml**

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
        <artifactId>portal-service</artifactId>
        <version>${liferay.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
        <artifactId>util-bridges</artifactId>
        <version>${liferay.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
        <artifactId>util-taglib</artifactId>
        <version>${liferay.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
        <artifactId>util-java</artifactId>
        <version>${liferay.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.portlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Next, I created a portlet class to extend MVCPortlet of Util Bridges:

**`MyPortlet` class**

```java
package com.csc.demo.portlet;

import com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet;

public class MyPortlet extends MVCPortlet{

}
```

But I can't extend it with error notifier `MVCPortlet cannot be resolved`? In *pom.xml* file, it added Util Bridges already, but when I check in Maven Dependencies, its gone? I have no idea about this? Can anyone help me and explain why? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Have the scope `provided` for util-bridges. The reason for "provided" is that the util-bridges should be local to the web app and it is not a global library. You can consider that MVCPortlet.java is a gift from Liferay to us. It is not a standard portlet bridge.

The standard Liferay portlet bridge is `com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet`, which is a part of portlet-service and it is available in global path and you do not need as local.

Comment: that's why I don't understand why? Any idea?